# How to preserve . in WordPress slug?

Tags: wordpress

I want to keep some characters such as . in WordPress slug. 
Even if I edit the slug to include the ., WordPress removes it upon saving.
I use SEO Slugs plugin. Does any one know of a function which lets me keep the . in the slugs?

Thanks,
Andreas G.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Advanced Permalinks](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/advanced-permalinks/) plugin adds the ability to use `.` in your permalinks.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Can you tell me how do I do this with the plugin?

Comment: Hi, I tried Advanced Permalinks plugin and it did keep the period in permalinks.But I am getting 404 errors for all category pages. I have not changed the category base or for that matter any other setting in the plugin.

Answer (score 0):

This is a general behavior on the part of WordPress. The routine responsible for it is `santize_title_with_dashes()`, found in `wp-includes/formatting.php`. This is invoked from a number of places, including as the `slug` filter. According to the code, this limits the string to `A-Za-z0-9_` and `-`. Whitespace goes to '-' and everything else is deleted.

Short of rewriting of your theme and/or plugin (and perhaps even more than that) I don't think there's much you can do about it.